# Hadoop, MapReduce: how to add second node to mapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, configuration, mapreduce, cluster-computing

I have a Hadoop 0.2.2 cluster of 2 nodes. On the first machine I start:

- namenode
- datanode
- NodeManager
- ResourceManager
- JobHistoryServer

On the second I start all those as well, except for namenode:

- datanode
- NodeManager
- ResourceManager
- JobHistoryServer

My `mapred-site.xml` on both machines contains:

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>firstMachine:54311</value>
</property>
```

My core-site.xml on both machines contains:

```
<property>
   <name>fs.default.name</name>
   <value>hdfs://firstMachine:9000</value>
</property>
```

The console at `http://firstMachine:50070` reports 2 nodes:

```
 Live Nodes     :   2 (Decommissioned: 0)
```

However the console at `http://firstMachine:8088` (the one with the map reduce jobs history and all that), keeps saying:

```
Active Nodes: 1
```

Also, executing a map reduce with or without the second machine, Hadoop yields pretty much the same performance. Tried it with the wordcout example, using 4 big files.

My question is: how can I check if my map reduce is actually executed on multiple (2 in this case) machines, and not just the one where it is launched?

If my Hadoop map reduce in fact does NOT see the other Hadoop instance, how to I make it see it (how can I configure it to run the map reduce on 2 machines) ?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I've found the answer. Apparently in version 2.2 most (all?) of the stuff that was related to mapred is now moved to yarn. So instead of using the mapred-site.xml file, I had to use the yarn-site.xml file, and add to it :

```
<property>
 <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
 <value>firstMachine</value>
</property>
```

(note that I didn't have to add the port, only the host is to be declared here. The port will be used in its default value).

Now the console displays 2 active nodes, and the map/reduce job is about 20% faster.