# How to add multiple nodes to Hadoop 2.2.0 Yarn?

Tags: xml, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a work-in-progress Hadoop cluster configuration including four machines but in the MapReduce WebUI I see only one active node instead of four, the `olympus` name node where the MapReduce is triggered from.

I'm aware of similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861173/hadoop-mapreduce-how-to-add-second-node-to-mapreduce) but doing that still doesn't help maybe due to version differences?

My start up seems to be working all right:

```
deploy@olympus:~$ start-dfs.sh && start-yarn.sh
Starting namenodes on [olympus]
olympus: starting namenode, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/hadoop-deploy-namenode-olympus.out
zeus: starting datanode, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/hadoop-deploy-datanode-zeus.out
hera: starting datanode, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/hadoop-deploy-datanode-hera.out
olympus: starting datanode, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/hadoop-deploy-datanode-olympus.out
poseidon: starting datanode, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/hadoop-deploy-datanode-poseidon.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/hadoop-deploy-secondarynamenode-olympus.out
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/yarn-deploy-resourcemanager-olympus.out
poseidon: starting nodemanager, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/yarn-deploy-nodemanager-poseidon.out
olympus: starting nodemanager, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/yarn-deploy-nodemanager-olympus.out
zeus: starting nodemanager, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/yarn-deploy-nodemanager-zeus.out
hera: starting nodemanager, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/yarn-deploy-nodemanager-hera.out
```

My `yarn-site.xml` looks like this in all four machines:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resourcetracker.address</name>
    <value>olympus:8025</value>
    <description>Enter your ResourceManager hostname.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>olympus:8030</value>
    <description>Enter your ResourceManager hostname.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>olympus:8050</value>
    <description>Enter your ResourceManager hostname.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
    <value>olympus:8041</value>
    <description>Enter your ResourceManager hostname.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

My `mapred-site.xml` looks like this in all four machines:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>olympus:8021</value>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
    <value>olympus:10020</value>
    <description>Enter your JobHistoryServer hostname.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
    <value>olympus:19888</value>
    <description>Enter your JobHistoryServer hostname.</description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

My `core-site.xml` looks like this in all four machines:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://olympus:8020/</value>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

My `hdfs-site` looks like this in all four machines:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:/home/deploy/hdfs/name</value>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:/home/deploy/hdfs/data</value>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Finally my `slaves` file looks like this in all four machines:

```
 olympus
 zeus
 hera
 poseidon
```

**UDPATE:**

I see the following error message in the log file `yarn-deploy-nodemanager-zeus.log`:

```
 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8031
```

Where is this `0.0.0.0:8031` defined as part of yarn or hadoop configuration? shouldn't it be trying to connect to `olympus:8031` or `olympus:8032` instead?

Comment: Please check for services on slaves via jps. They are working or not?

Comment: Yes they were working, in fact I think I got the solution the problem was a misspelled configuration name `yarn.resourcemanager.resourcetracker.address` should be `yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was a misspelled configuration. Changing `yarn-site.xml`:

from

```
<property>
 <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resourcetracker.address</name>
 <value>olympus:8025</value>
 <description>Enter your ResourceManager hostname.</description>
</property>
```

to

```
<property>
 <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
 <value>olympus:8025</value>
 <description>Enter your ResourceManager hostname.</description>
</property>
```

solved the problem. There was a missing hyphen in `resource-tracker` probably copied from an outdated configuration sample somewhere.

Comment: The continous renaming of the configuration parameters is such a pain in the ass, similar problems have snagged me as well. It makes looking at example configurations a minefield that may waste more time than it saves. Unfortunately the documentation leaves much to be desired.

Answer (score 3):

For your `NodeManagers` on `zeus`, `hera` and `poseidon` to be able to register onto the `ResourceManager` daemon, in order to then appear in the live nodes list, the port `8032`  on `olympus` must be accessible.

Typically stock OS defaults turn firewalls on, which can get in the way of this happening auto-magically after your `start-dfs.sh && start-yarn.sh`. You can try to disable your OS's firewall if it is enabled, and retry the same startup and things should work. Most Linux OS's firewalls can be turned off with a `service iptables stop`, but you may check and use what applies to your OS.

If the firewall is down, then you will need to log on to either one of `zeus`, `hera` or `poseidon` and check the log files `/opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/yarn-deploy-nodemanager-*.log` and `/opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/hadoop-deploy-datanode.log` for errors (of connectivity sort, etc.) and then troubleshoot further based on what is presented in it.